# The custom painting is not being displayed - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a class that extends CustomPaint and overridden the paint() method. For some reason is not being displayed I tried a lot of ways,

also When I run my app, the custom painting is not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason why custom painting widgets do not display in Flutter is because they are not being added to the widget tree. To add a custom painting widget to the widget tree, you need to use the CustomPaint.add() method. For example:

```
class MyCustomPaint extends CustomPaint {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Paint your custom painting here.
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint.add(
        child: Container(),
        painter: MyCustomPaint(),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

In this example, the MyCustomPaint widget is being added to the widget tree as a child of the Container widget. This ensures that the custom painting will be displayed when the app is run.

I also suggest to read this blog [a-deep-dive-into-custompaint](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-custompaint-in-flutter-47ab44e3f216),

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: Actually the answer is quite simple,and not mean is generated by AI the question need that,might he translate the answer from different language